# Referencing an equation in align mode

Tags: cross-referencing

Let say I have an labeled-equation like,

[image]

And I want to refer this equation in align mode like,

[image]

I want to know how can this be done using label and ref tools in latex? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by adding a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as you reference in normal text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:abc}
a = b + c
\end{equation}
%
\begin{align*}
e + f &= g \\
\overset{\text{by \eqref{eq:abc}}}{\Longrightarrow} m + n &= p
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

**Edit:**
I forgot on "by" ... corrected now

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
                  a+b & = c       \label{eq:1}  \\
\xRightarrow{\text by \eqref{eq:1} }} m+n & =p
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below coding solved your problem:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}

a=b+c\label{eq1}

\end{align}

\begin{align}

e+f&=g\label{eq2}\\

\xRightarrow{\text{by \eqref{eq1}}}m+n&=p

\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `amsmath` is loaded by `mathtools`, so it is not necessary to load it again ...

Comment: blank lines aren't allowed in math mode.  (perhaps this is just an accident of how this was input, but it's something you should rmember.)